# IoC registration for wrapper class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, decorator, simple-injector

I have interface `IA` and implementations `A:IA` and `B:IA`. The `B` implementation has a dependency on `IA` with constructor DI so that `B.ctor(IA)`.

The intent of this design is to wrap `A` with `B` and allow them to be used interchangeably. `A` is an adapter to a database, and `B` allows caching of that data.

`IA` is also depending on by provider classes in this system, so that when I register those providers I would like to use an instance of `B`. My object graph should basically look as follows:

```
new Provider(
    new B(
        new A(
            new DbContex("constr")
        )
    )
)
```

I have considered using a tagging interface such that `IB:IA` and `B:IB`, but then I would need to depend on `IB` on my providers instead of `IA` which would not be ideal.

I have also considered using a factory for `IA` that creates an instance of `B` using an instance of `A`, but that feels wrong.

So I guess I am looking for some way of accomplishing this registration using the simpleinjector IoC container.

**Example code**

```
public class A : IA
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public A(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        // Do stuff to get and
        // return value from database.
    }

    public void Set<T>(T value)
    {
        // Do stuff to set value
        // in database.
    }
}
```

Wrapper class:

```
public class B : IA
{
    private readonly IA _adapter;

    public B(IA adapter)
    {
        _adapter = adapter;
    }

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        // Do stuff to get and
        // return value from cache
        // or database adapter.
    }

    public void Set<T>(T value)
    {
        // Do stuff to set value
        // in cache and database.
    }
}
```

Consumer of `IA`:

```
public class Provider
{
    private readonly IA _adapter;

    public Provider(IA adapter)
    {
        _adapter = adapter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is known as the [decorator pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Simple Injector has excellent support for applying decorators, probably the best support compared to other mainstream IoC containers.

You can read all about the decorator subsystem here: 
[Aspect-Oriented Programming](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aop.html#decoration) in the documentation.

For this basic case the registrations needed are straightforward:

```
container.Register<IA, A>();
container.RegisterDecorator<IA, B>();
```

And don't forget to put 'IA' in the ctor of B.